# reorder variables in upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-decomposition

I have an upper triangular system

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{00} & a_{01} & a_{02} & a_{03} \\
0 & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
0 & 0 & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_0 \\
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
b_3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

My goal is to remove $x_1$ from the system and just have

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{00}' & a_{01}' & a_{02}' \\
0 & a_{11}' & a_{12}' \\
 0 & 0 & a_{22}' \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_0' \\
b_1' \\
b_2' \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I think this is possible by reordering the states and then doing a QR factorization which would give something like the following from which the top row could be removed.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_0'' & a_1'' & a_2'' & a_3'' \\
0 & a_{00}' & a_{01}' & a_{02}' \\
0 & 0 & a_{11}' & a_{12}' \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a_{22}' \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_0 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b'' \\
b_0' \\
b_1' \\
b_2'
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I'll leave my method here to help others solve the problem in the future. Given a system $A \bar{x} = \bar{b}$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{00} & a_{01} & a_{02} & a_{03} \\
0 & a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
0 & 0 & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_0 \\
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
b_3
\end{bmatrix},
$$

first we'll reorder the state vector so the states to be dropped are at the beginning

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{01} & a_{00} & a_{02} & a_{03} \\
a_{11} & 0 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
0 & 0 & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_0 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_0 \\
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
b_3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Call the above $A_\text{reorder} \bar{x}_\text{reorder} = \bar{b}$. Then take the QR factorization of the matrix

$$
QR = A_\text{reorder},
$$

and apply the rotation to $\bar{b}$

$$
\bar{b}'' = Q^T \bar{b}.
$$

We now have a new upper triangular system $R \bar{x}_\text{reorder} = \bar{b}''$, and so we can just extract the bottom three equations

$$
\begin{align}
A' &= R[2:4, 2:4], \\
\vec{b}' &= \bar{b}''[2:4].
\end{align}
$$

This gives us our desired system

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{00}' & a_{01}' & a_{02}' \\
0 & a_{11}' & a_{12}' \\
 0 & 0 & a_{22}' \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_0' \\
b_1' \\
b_2' \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Simple example in python:

````
from numpy import *
from numpy.linalg import solve
from scipy.linalg import qr

b = array([0, 1, 2, 3])
A = array([[2, 3, 7, 1], [0, 2, 4, 5], [0, 0, 1, 8], [0, 0, 0, 2]])

indices_drop = [1]
indices_keep = [0, 2, 3]

x = solve(A, b)

indices = indices_drop + indices_keep

A_reorder = A[:, indices]

[Q, R] = qr(A_reorder, mode="full")

b_pp = Q.T @ b

A_p = R[-len(indices_keep) :, -len(indices_keep) :]
b_p = b_pp[-len(indices_keep) :]

x_p = solve(A_p, b_p)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

From the second row

$ x_1 = \dfrac{1}{a_{11}} \left( b_1 - a_{12} x_2 - a_{13} x_3 \right)$

The third and fourth equations will not change, because they do not depend on $x_1$.  For the first equation, it'll become

$ a_{00} x_0 + \dfrac{a_{01}}{a_{11}} \left( b_1 - a_{12} x_2 - a_{13} x_3 \right) + a_{02} x_2 + a_{03} x_3 = b_0$

Thus the first equation becomes

$  a_{00} x_0 + \left(  a_{02} - \dfrac{a_{01} a_{12}}{a_{11}}\right) x_2 + \left(a_{03} - \dfrac{ a_{01} a_{13}}{a_{11}}\right) x_3 = b_0 - \dfrac{a_{01}}{a_{11}} b_1 $